# Open subscheme of an affine scheme such that the map to the spectrum of global sections is not an open immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $U \subset X$ an open subscheme.  **Is the canonical morphism $U \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U))$ always an open immersion?**

When $U$ is quasi-compact, this is certainly true (see e.g. [[Stacks 01P5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01P5)]).  It's also true whenever $X$ is reduced, though I don't have a reference.  I suspect this all breaks down in the non-quasi-affine, non-reduced case, but then I saw [this answer of Matt Emerton](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13506/is-the-mapping-from-a-scheme-to-its-global-sections-a-closed-map) that seems to claim it is true for any affine $X$. (That same answer then may suggest in an edit that $U$ does need to be quasi-affine — ultimately it is left ambiguous.)

Does anyone have a reference or counterexample to settle this?